# Xamarin+Monotouch: Could not AOT the assembly '.../obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/Build/Touch.exe' (MT3001)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, linker, xamarin

I'm getting the following error during compilation when "Linker Behavior: Link All Assemblies" option is enabled:

> Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly
>   '.../obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/Build/Touch.exe' (MT3001)

What is interesting that with "Link Nothing" or "Link SDK Assemblies Only" solution is compiled just fine.

Any thoughts how to fix or at least diagnose this issue?
I'm using Xamarin Studio + MonoTouch (latest stable releases)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Look at the full build output (you'll find it in the Errors pad in Xamarin Studio, there's a button you can click to show it).

Feel free to ask again if you don't understand what's happening in the build output.

Comment: these two warning all I have. But it is just a warnings. May be linker some how drop part of code (assuming that it is not used) and drop the reference to system.net.http?
warning MT3005: The dependency 'System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' of the assembly 'HostMe.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was not found. Please review the project's references.
warning MT3006: Could not compute a complete dependency map for the project. This will result in slower build times because Xamarin.iOS
AOT Compilation exited with code 134

Comment: That is in fact exactly the problem: Xamarin.iOS does not include System.Net.Http,v1.5.0.0 (it's v2.0.5.0, and the API it exposes is likely different, causing the AOT compiler to complain when HostMe.Core is using API from System.Net.Http that Xamarin.iOS's version does not have). The solution is to create a new Xamarin.iOS library project and add the source code for HostMe.Core there so that you create a proper Xamarin.iOS library you can reference in your main project.

Comment: HostMe.Core is PCL project and all the benefits we got from PCL we will lose if we switch to the native Xamarin.iOS project. Any chance to force use that library I have (http.dll v1.5 pcl)?

Comment: I tried to include System.Net.Http (v 1.5.0.0) Xamarin.iOS project (which is used PCL) and now I got another error: MonoTouch Business version 6.4.1 using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
AOT Compilation exited with code 134, 

error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/alexeys/Desktop/Sources/Touch/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/Build/Touch.exe'

Comment: Can you pastebin the full Build Output?